# getElementById returning Null in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dk3L.png)

Trying to make a simple Chrome Extension where it tracks how long you've been on a page. I've been having a lot of trouble with this. When I run the extension the debugger goes through a loop of saying it cannot the set the `innerhtml` of null because it is unable to find the element with id `elapsedTime`. In the debugger when I inspect the document the element isn't there. I assume this has something to do with the html not being loaded when the icon is not clicked but am unsure how to deal with this. But either way! Any help is appreciated.

background.js, manifest.json, and index.html respectively

```js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab){
    if (tab.status == 'complete') {
        let startDate = new Date();
        let elapsedTime = 0;

        setInterval(function() {
                timeNow = new Date();
                elapsedTime = timeNow - startDate;
                document.getElementById('elapsedTime').innerHTML = elapsedTime;
        },100);
    };
});
```

```css
{
  "name": "Timer-Extension",
  "description": "A timer that displays how long you have been on a page",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "src/img/clock-16.png",
    "default_popup": "src/index.html",
    "default_title": "Timer-Extension"
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "src/img/clock-16.png",
    "48": "src/img/clock-48.png",
    "128": "src/img/clock-128.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["src/js/background.js"]
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <p id = 'elapsedTime'></p>
        <script type='text/javascript' src = js/background.js></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried <div> instead of <p> ?

Comment: @maddy23285 why would that make any difference?

Comment: Or check url if you are on right page. If yes, add few more elements of different types and ispect the page.

Comment: So if the element is not there, than how can it select it? Is the html supposed to be injected from your extension?

Comment: There is no right page because it's a Chrome Extension. This is called whenever I open a new tab, i.e. why I have the Chrome listener. And that's the problem, I have no idea why my element isn't there because I can see it is, but it's not being loaded.